# can not pass :font attribute to face-remap-add-relative

Tags: org-mode, faces

The doc for `face-remap-add-relative` said:

> This function adds specs as relative remappings for face `face` in the current buffer. `specs` should be a list where each element is either a face name, or a property list of attribute/value pairs.

And give 2 example:

```
;; Remap the 'escape-glyph' face into a combination
;; of the 'highlight' and 'italic' faces:
(face-remap-add-relative 'escape-glyph 'highlight 'italic)

;; Increase the size of the 'default' face by 50%:
(face-remap-add-relative 'default :height 1.5)
```

I'm able to reproduce the first example with this code:

```
;Function only run in Org mode, to separate it with emac.
(defface your-new-face-remap
    '((t (:font "Fira Mono" :height 130)))
    "My custom font for org mode default.")

(defun your-new-face-mode
    (face-remap-add-relative 'default 'your-new-face-remap-style))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'your-new-face-mode)
```

But when I try to simplified my code with the 2nd example, it won't work:

```
(defun your-new-face-mode
    (face-remap-add-relative 'default :font "Fira Mono" :height 130))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'your-new-face-mode)
```

But when I delete the `:font "Fira Mono"` and only keep the `:height 130` then it works. So why does `face-remap-add-relative` don't accept `:font`?

Comment: I believe I encountered this issue several months ago with a much older version of Emacs, and I resolved the problem by using `:family`  instead of `:font`.  Give that a try ...  I also used lowercase, such as `:family "bitstream charter"` and I'm running Emacs on an older Debian OS.

Comment: @lawlist, I currently use emac 28.2 on Window, but you are right, when using `:family` the code work, so then maybe I have to be more careful with what attribute for different function.